# Search left join null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql statement for mysql that matches a string to words in two databases. I want to exclude results that are also in another table, but when I add the left join of conv_progress, it breaks the statement. Anyone have any ideas how to exclude entries that are in another table?

**Works**

```
SELECT video.*,
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as cscore, 
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as htscore
FROM video
LEFT JOIN tags ON video.vid_id=tags.vid_id
null
WHERE
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP BY video.vid_id
ORDER BY cscore DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

**Broken**

```
SELECT video.*,
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as cscore, 
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as htscore
FROM video
LEFT JOIN tags ON video.vid_id=tags.vid_id
LEFT JOIN conv_progress on video.vid_id=conv_progress.vid_id where conv_progress.vid_id is null
WHERE
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP BY video.vid_id
ORDER BY cscore DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `conv_progress.vid_id is null` into the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT video.*,
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as cscore, 
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as htscore
FROM video
LEFT JOIN tags ON video.vid_id=tags.vid_id
LEFT JOIN conv_progress on video.vid_id=conv_progress.vid_id 
WHERE
  (
    MATCH(video.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
    MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  ) 
  AND conv_progress.vid_id is null
GROUP BY video.vid_id
ORDER BY cscore DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `NOT EXISTS` instead of join

```
SELECT video.*,
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as cscore, 
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as htscore
FROM video
LEFT JOIN tags ON video.vid_id=tags.vid_id
null
WHERE
  (
  MATCH(video.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
  MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  )AND(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM conv_progress WHERE video.vid_id=conv_progress.vid_id))
 GROUP BY video.vid_id
ORDER BY cscore DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

Comment: thanks buddy. Wouldn't a nested query be slightly slower though?

Comment: I guess it depends. Sometimes `exists` can be optimised very well... you have to test it to see which one is quicker with your data.

Comment: You can use EXPLAIN before the SELECT part to see how the database searches for its results. I think that a index on the tags.vid_id column would be a good perfomance boost.